# Rails autotest with ubuntu and remote growl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, autotest, growl, growlnotify

I am using ubuntu to develop my rails apps in a virtual machine and I want to send growl notifications in my windows which is in a LAN (growl exists in windows also).

I wrote a simple script to send notifications from ubuntu to windows remotely and it worked perfectly (with the ruby-growl gem), but I was wondering if autotest/growl supports remote notifications and how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fun hacking. http://github.com/svoop/autotest-growl/blob/master/lib/autotest/growl.rb#L87

Answer (score 0):

autotest/growl doesn't use ruby-growl so I don't know how that runs on linux, but does adding `Autotest::Growl::remote_notification = true` to your `~/.autotest` file do what you need?